# How to get the length of a database column?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm accessing a MySQL database using PDO in PHP. Say I have a table with a column of type CHAR(30), or INT(5):

1. there's a way to get the column length (the values `30` and `5`) from a PHP script using PDO, that is not database-specific?
2. if not, there's a way to get that value using PDO anyway?
3. if not, there's a way to get that value using PHP?

Comment: Do you want the length of the column's definition, of a given field (obviously invariant in the case of a fixed-length datatype such as `CHAR`)?  Do you want the length in *characters* or *bytes*?

Comment: Yes, I want the length of the column's definition. The type of the column can also not be CHAR, but INT, FLOAT...

Comment: May I ask why do you need that?

Comment: @YourCommonSense: To set the `maxlength` of inputs without hardcode. I do _not_ need it for safety.

Comment: `SHOW FIELDS FROM table`

Comment: @u_mulder: good :) Is this SQL standard?

Comment: @LucasMalor I didn't checked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This informations should be available in the [`information_schema.columns`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html) table:

```
SELECT CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_SCALE FROM information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'your_table_name'
```

There's different columns for string lengths (`CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH`) and numerical lengths (`NUMERIC_PRECISION`).

**Update:**

To work-around a limitation/bug of MySQL where the lengths are not always reported correctly, it might be necessary to parse the definitions themselves and extract the number within brackets.

Comment: Do you know if this can be used also with other databases (Postgres, sqlite, Oracle...)?

Comment: Postgres has a [similar feature](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/infoschema-columns.html) and presumably the others do, too.

Comment: There's somthing strange... I have an unsigned mediumint(8), and its NUMERIC_PRECISION is 7. Furthermore an unsigned tinyint(1) has NUMERIC_PRECISION = 3.

Comment: You can always interpret `TINYINT(1)` by extracting the number from within the brackets, right?

Comment: Yes, but I'm lazy :D Well, if you'll update the answer with infos of your last comment I'll accept it :)